# Alfresco Share: Error on accepting site invitation from email

Tags: alfresco, ecm

It's on Alfresco Community 4.0.d.

1. Invite a user to a site
2. Invited user will receive invitation email which has accept & reject link
3. If the user click the accept link, an error page will be showed up:

> **Processing invite acceptance failed Unfortunately, your invite acceptance could not be registered. Either you have already accepted or rejected the invite, or the inviter cancelled your invitation.**

Error log from catalina.out:

```
2012-09-04 15:15:53,845  ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-8080-94] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: A valid SecureContext was not provided in the RequestContext
 net.sf.acegisecurity.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: A valid SecureContext was not provided in the RequestContext
    at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:481)
    at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:359)
    at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionInterceptor$1.execute(RetryingTransactionInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:388)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionInterceptor.invoke(RetryingTransactionInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy8.exists(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleServiceImpl.checkForCopy(RuleServiceImpl.java:1269)
    at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleServiceImpl.canExecuteRule(RuleServiceImpl.java:1249)
    at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleServiceImpl.executePendingRule(RuleServiceImpl.java:1161)
    at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleServiceImpl.executePendingRulesImpl(RuleServiceImpl.java:1114)
    at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleServiceImpl.executePendingRules(RuleServiceImpl.java:1087)
    at org.alfresco.repo.rule.RuleTransactionListener.beforeCommit(RuleTransactionListener.java:57)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.AlfrescoTransactionSupport$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.doBeforeCommit(AlfrescoTransactionSupport.java:747)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.AlfrescoTransactionSupport$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.doBeforeCommit(AlfrescoTransactionSupport.java:727)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.AlfrescoTransactionSupport$TransactionSynchronizationImpl.beforeCommit(AlfrescoTransactionSupport.java:687)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:927)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:737)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.alfresco.util.transaction.SpringAwareUserTransaction.commit(SpringAwareUserTransaction.java:472)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:410)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:462)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:500)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:275)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:372)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you got some custom rules defined within the repository? Based on the stack trace, it looks like that is what is causing your problem.

Comment: @WillAbson You're right! I deleted my custom rules and the invitation link works just fine. Now, how can I have custom rules within the repository without interfering the invitation link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that your rules are not too broadly-defined - try to specify filters so that you only match the exact type of content that you are interested in. I can't see why your rules would be getting fired by the site invite being processed, unless you have are matching all content items.

If you can clarify the question to describe the rules you have set up and what you're trying to achieve, it may be that someone can help you a little more.

Comment: You're right again Will. I have one rule which adds some aspects to new documents that matching all content items within User Homes directory. It's the only custom rule I have. I'm gonna try your suggestion and test it with several custom rules.

Comment: Ok, I've made some custom rules avoiding all items in matching criteria. So far accept link in site invitation mail is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to access from the link in the mail directly to the same browser where you were logged in with the user who sent the invite? This seems an authentication with wrong credentials problem. Try to use another computer if you can, or just wipe out cache and cookies, or use another browser with no stored passwords of previous users. Let me know if helps.